# how to convert list to dataframe

Tags: r

my data

```
df = list(personaId = 0, pacienteId = 1408849, sexoId = 0, departamentoResidencia = "CUNDINAMARCA", 
    municipioResidencia = "ANAPOIMA", tipoIdentificacion = "Cédula de ciudadanía", 
    numeroIdentificacion = "12345", primerNombre = "ivone", segundoNombre = "", 
    primerApellido = "moya", segundoApellido = NULL, fechaNacimiento = "1924-11-17T00:00:00")
```

Im trying to convert this to a dataframe with no luck. I know im missing something simple.

My desired output

```
personaId pacienteId sexoId departamentoResidencia municipioResidencia tipoIdentificacion      numeroIdentificacion primerNombre segundoNombre primerApellido segundoApellido fechaNacimiento 
0         1408849       0   CUNDINAMARCA           ANAPOIMA            Cédula de ciudadanía    12345                ivone                      moya           NULL            1924-11-17T00:00:00
```

Comment: What did you try? Maybe `as.data.frame()`?

Comment: It works with a simple `as.data.frame()` around it -- provided you remove the `NULL` component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to maintain the column `segundoApellido` which has `NULL` you may need to change it to `NA` and then a simple `data.frame` call should work.

```
df[sapply(df, is.null)] <- NA
data.frame(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
bind_cols(df)
```